# How to create date object and set date in 1 line in typescript?

Tags: typescript, date, object

Hi I have 2 lines of code, 1 creating date object, 1 set new date to yesterday.

```
yesterday = new Date () ;
this.yesterday.setDate(this.yesterday.getDate()-1);
```

How can I simplfy the code and do the work in a single line?

Something like this

```
yesterday = new Date ().setDate(this.yesterday.getDate()-1);
```

Or this

```
yesterday = new Date ()=>{setDate(this.yesterday.getDate()-1)};
```

Is it even possible? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Turns out there are a moment.js library that helps you fiddle around date and time instead of using native javascript object. It makes the whole date and time data integration much faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is Possible

```
const yesterday = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 1))
```

Or

```
const yesterday = new Date(Date.now() - 864e5); // 864e5 == 86400000 == 24*60*60*1000
```

Comment: There is a potential race condition with the first code in this answer if the month changes between the first and second calls to `new Date()`, you could end up with (for example) `September 30th` when you were expecting `August 30th`